# Accessing Subclass Field from Array of Superclass?

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism

I just recently started learning java, so I'm having a little trouble understanding what I think is a polymorphism issue. I'm trying to program a chess game, so I have a an array of superclass called `GamePiece` for which the subclass `PawnPiece` extends. I have a method in both classes called `MovePiece()` which changes the position of the piece. When I use `MovePiece()`, changes the position values of the `PawnPiece`, but when I try to call the positions in my main code, it gives me the unchanged position of 'GamePiece'. Here's some of my code:

```
public class GamePiece {
    int position;

    //Constructor
    public GamePiece(int x){
       position=x;
    }
    public void MovePiece(int positionOfMove){};
}

public class PawnPiece extends GamePiece{
    int positionPawn;

    //Subclass Constructor
    public PawnPiece(int x){
        super(x);
    }

    public void MovePiece(int positionOfMovePawn){
       positionPawn=x;
}

public classChessMain{
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        GamePiece[] allPieces = new GamePiece[32];
        int startPositionPawn = 9;     //Arbitrary#
        allPieces[8]=new PawnPiece(int startPositionPawn); //index is arbitrary
        int playerMove = 5;     //Arbitrary#
        allPieces[8].MovePiece(playerMove);
    }
}
```

The last line gives me the initial position (9 in this case), but I know if I could access the position of `PawnPiece`, it would give me 5. Any help all you coding wizards out there? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: `positionPawnX=x;` -> x is not accessible at this scope

Comment: @sansix Whoops. Should have just been `positionPawn`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple issues:

1. The class `GamePiece` and the method `MovePiece` should be abstract. This way, you will force any subclass that chooses to be a `GamePiece` to implement its own `MovePiece` method.
2. You are storing the position in two places:

   - You have `int position` in `GamePiece`
   - You have `int positionPawn` in `PawnPiece`.

   You probably want only one of these: get rid of the `positionPawn` in `PawnPiece` and use `position` in `GamePiece`.
3. (Optional) Java convention is to have method names begin with a lower case letter: rename `MovePiece` to `movePiece`

Comment: Excellent! I understand what I was doing now. I guess my issue was a lot simpler than I made it out to be. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

From the code  given I can guess that in the PawnPiece you are updating variable **positionPawn**, and then check variable **position**. So you are writing to wrong place.

Comment: Thanks! I deleted `int positionPawn` and just use `int position` from GamePiece now.